# Thumbnails in Files are too small (22.04)

Tags: nautilus, files, 22.04, thumbnails

When I open a folder in Files, I can choose between a file list or thumbnails. In the case of images - a miniature of the image. Then I can zoom, but I can only zoom up to '133%', which still gives me VERY small images of 3 cm (about 1 inch) width. That makes it very hard to distinguish which image I want to open into full screen view. This limitation seems utterly primitive...

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: this is a rant, not a question...

Comment: The question is - of course - how to enlarge the thumbnail images...